# Python - Geemap get the image of the Map at a specific point

Tags: image, image-processing, google-earth-engine, geemap

I have some understanding problems regarding the geemap and ee in python environment.
What I want to do is quite simple : do some measurements with the image of a map (area calculation).

So what I have coded now :

- Get the map with latitude, longitude and zoom defined ;
- Get the satellite view ;
- Get the scale (m/pixel) ;

What I don't achieve :

- Extract the image of the map (png, jpg or file for image processing).

The code :

`
Map = geemap.Map()

```
lat = 48.858370
lon = 2.294481

Map.set_center(lat=lat, lon=lon, zoom=18)
point = ee.Geometry.Point(lon, lat)
feature = ee.Feature(point)

# Map.view_mode = 'HYBRID'
Map.add_basemap('SATELLITE')
Map.add_ee_layer(feature)
scale = Map.get_scale()
print("Scale : " + str(scale) + " m/pixel")

download_dir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Documents')
png_file = os.path.join(download_dir, 'my_map.png')
image  = Map.to_image()
# image = Map.to_image()
# print(image)
Map
```

`

The image generated is a simple screenshot that I don't want because I specifically want the map in PNG (or other).
I also understood that there is the Google Maps Static API but it does include billing etc which I don't want because it is a small personal project (no lucrative)

I tried a lot of things but it doesn't work as I want : the satellite view as you can see in the image.[Output Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwrR5.jpg)

In a perfect way, I want to define a centered rectangle around the lat,lon to extract the image. I tried the collection but the resolution is really bad so maybe I don't use it in the good way.

`
lat = 48.858370
lon = 2.294481

```
image_size = 1000

roi = ee.Geometry.Point(lon, lat).buffer(image_size/2).bounds()

collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')

image = collection.filterBounds(roi).first()

clipped_image = image.clip(roi)

url = clipped_image.getThumbURL({'min': 0, 'max': 3000, 'dimensions': 1000})

Image(url=url)
```

`

The output is really bad so I think I don't use really good even if I change COPERNICUS to other collection (LANDSAT etc)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpc4a.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find an answer using earth engine.
Instead I use the Google Maps API Static, you can use it for free if you don't exceed the minimum charged requests.